# Extensions not allowed in v2 certificate in Android Studio

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am developing an Android Application but when I am trying to build the application, it gives me error:

> Gradle Sync Failed Error:Extensions not allowed in v2 certificate".

I am using:

*Android Studio: 2.2.2.*

*Gradle Version: 2.2.2*

My `build.gradle` file is :

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

aaptOptions
        {
            cruncherEnabled = false
        }

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    applicationId "com.myproject.src"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary=true
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("path_for_keystore")
        storePassword "password"
        keyAlias "Alias"
        keyPassword "password"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false;
    disable 'InvalidPackage' 
    disable 'OldTargetApi'
}}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Older version of some external library (butterknife) was causing the issue.
After updating to the latest version resolved the issue.

Comment: It'd be useful if you mentioned which library